# How can I find a lost item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've lost Morekei, 100% magicka regen, and I have no idea how. I've been looping through all of the shopkeepers I might have somehow sold it to but no one seems to have it.

I've got this game on PC. Is there any way I can gain information about where in the game world it is is? Conosle commands or looking through the game files?

I can create another one (anyone know it's ID?), but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: "I'd prefer not to do that." Why? There are plenty of items for you to find that were "lost for the ages," so you're just enhancing the lore of Skyrim. You sold it to a shopkeeper, who passed it on to a hapless traveler, driven mad by its enchantments, or something (merchants unload their inventory every once in a while). Or you accidentally dropped it. Or put it in a chest that wasn't yours, which, as we all know, periodically sends its contents to Oblivion. The only real solution here is to use the console, as there's no guarantee you can re-find it even if you remember where you left it.

Comment: Ooohh I hate this kind of issue, I had it when looking for a book once. I would recommend going back to where you found it in the first place and look there. Also check the evidence chest in the prisons - I've found some of my lost stuff in them even though I'm sure it wasn't stolen.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I put it on a weapon rack in my house in Solitude. I walked in and saw it was missing. After about 20 minutes of searching, I found it had fallen off the rack, bounced around my basement (somehow) and ended up in the little room with the sleeping bag by the alchemy table...

Comment: Did you happen to lose it in a fight? Some of the higher level Draugr can use the Disarm shout. Lost a nice mace that way and had to scour the room for it.

Comment: @Tristan I ran into that in Oblivion once. Put a unique shield in a case, and when I came back it was gone. Eventually found it upstairs in a different room...

Comment: Clearly, most player houses in Tamriel are haunted. It's the only explanation.

Comment: Using the console command 'save "name" 1' will create a text dump of the save data in your saves folder named name.ess.txt, the item should pop up there if it is still in the world.

Answer (score 21):

On PC, you can find its ID with the `help "Item" 0` command, then use `player.additem ######`. A nearly complete list of all items with their IDs can be found on the [Unofficial Elder Scrolls Pages [UESP] Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Items).

I know you "prefer" not to do that, but it's your only option.

Console players cannot retrieve or spawn items that have disappeared and have generally a hard time getting back persistent items (like quest items or unique quest rewards) which have fallen through the many cracks of the world, though the details of this depend on the specific item and installed DLCs.

Comment: Just for reference, it's `player.additem 00061c8b 1` for Morokei: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Artifacts#Morokei

Comment: You could also search item IDs/RefIDs at the [UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Main_Page).

Comment: Xbox players can, if they *also* have Skyrim on PC, [move the save to PC, fix it with the console, then move it back to the Xbox](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/can-skyrims-console-savegames-be-migrated-to-pc).

Answer (score 9):

There's no way to search for items in Skyrim other than manually.

The Daedric Ebony Blade is a unique quest item so it is impossible to get another. (on the xbox)

I'd advise scouring your house for it, items are known to be randomly placed on the floor after you leave the building. Hopefully it will turn up in one of the corners.

As Peter suggests it's also worth checking evidence chests, though this would be a last resort imho.

Comment: The thing exists in the game, and its ID its stored somewhere in a savegame, so it's more like "nobody has written software to analyze savegames offline to locate lost items" than "there's no way".

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski Factual statements are generally understood to apply to the time when said. I wouldn't be surprised if someone made a tool to solve the issue in the time since I posted this. "There's no way" was valid 10 years ago and is not the same as "There will never be a way".

Comment: No, you are wrong. There *IS* a way: invest months of work to learn how to decode the format of the savegame, then use that knowledge to locate the item. I understand "there's no way to solve problem X" to mean "there is a rigorous proof that an algorithm that solves problem X cannot exist". Analyzing a binary file and finding an object reference in it is NOT the halting problem, and I hate when someone uses the words "there's no way" to mean "nobody has sat their ass down and done it".

Answer (score 1):

I've found lost items by using the console tcl command and walking through walls in my homes.

Some items get stuck behind tables, some are just floating out in the "Space" outside the cell.

Comment: Not items that are dropped, but well and truly *lost*.

Answer (score 0):

i think that's a bug, and i once was hit with it. if you happen to put in a weapon mannequin( he person like doll where you can put things to "try" it out) with another item, say archmage robes, it will disappear and never be found/lost.

best hope is to make one, as i also did that, knowing for myself that i already defeated Morekei.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sold it to a merchant they restock every 48 hours so the merchant might not have your stuff anymore.