# Can I regain the Ivory claw to use in Folgunthur?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I can vaguely remember selling my Ivory claw to somebody (not sure who) and now I need it in Folgunthur to get to the word of power.

Is there a way to get another one or locate where the original is?

Comment: The claw for each dungeon should be located in the dungeon itself.  Are you sure that is the one you need?

Comment: @bwarner Not the ivory claw. It's used in another dungeon as well. See my answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/47587/1177).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no way to find sold items, see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38444/is-there-any-way-to-find-a-sold-item) for further information. If you cannot find the ivory claw and are comfortable with cheating, you can use the console to get the item. This is also described in the question I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Quest items like this usually do not disappear from shops inventory. This is rather weird however because most claws are marked as "quest items" until you've used them. It is impossible to drop or sale quest items.

Most of the time the claw is inside the dungeon you will need it in, minimising the risk of losing it.

Answer (score -2):

The ivory claw should be in the dead body of Daynas Valen in Folgunthur.  If you've sold it, good luck trying to find that again.