# How to know where a claw key can be used?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Without Googling for the answer, is there a way in the game to know where a claw key can be used?

I have a few of those in my inventory and I don't know which one I already used and where I can use the rest.

Thanks all.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you usually get the claw in the dungeon or directly related to the dungeon, there is no indication when you are in the dungeon which claw will work.

Comment: @James When in a dungeon in front of a door which has to be opened with a claw, when trying to activate the door, it clearly says "You need the xyz claw to open this door". Of course you only have this if you don't have the needed one.

Comment: @LudoMC Sounds like you should have posted that as the answer to me. Attempting to use the door will let you know which one you require. I was just meaning there is no physical cue to look at to obtain that information.

Comment: @LudoMC This will still not tell you which of the dragon claws has the correct "code" when looked at.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes and this is why I didn't post it as an answer. It was just a reply on the first comment saying "there is no indication *when you are in the dungeon* which claw will work". However, when you have a claw in your inventory, you don't know where to use it and quest list doesn't help (I have one in mine which I didn't remember where to use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [Dragon Claws](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ivory_Dragon_Claw#Dragon_Claws):

```
//Claw - Dungeon
Coral Dragon Claw - Yngol's Barrow
Diamond Claw - Skuldafn
Ebony Claw - Korvanjund
Emerald Dragon Claw - Reachwater Rock
Glass Claw - Forelhost
Golden Claw - Bleak Falls Barrow
Iron Claw - Valthume
Ivory Dragon Claw - Folgunthur, Reachwater Rock
Ruby Dragon Claw - Dead Men's Respite
Sapphire Dragon Claw - Shroud Hearth Barrow
```

EDIT: I just read your *in game* clause. I don't think there is a way in game to do this, but as a good role player ;), you should have a notepad at your side to make annotations when you are playing this game. BTW, I'm lazy, and when I don't remember something that my character should know, I just use gaming.se or google.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the Ivory Claw, as noted in @Daniel Beck's answer, is also used in Reachwater Rock with the Emerald Claw -- there's two doors, and frustratingly neither door has any indication (that I saw) which claw to use. This makes it very easy to render the quest Forbidden Legend uncompleteable -- if you sell off your dragon claws after you use them, you won't have the Ivory Claw anymore when you reach the final dungeon in this quest.

Answer (score 1):

Most dragon claws are really simple, use them in the dungeon you got them from (see the other answer and its link to UESP). They are usually a big deal, so just remember where you picked them up.

There is one dungeon where you need two claws: Reachwater Rock. You get one of the claws from another dungeon. When you have the quest to go there, you already have the other claw.

> There are two gates/doors in Reachwater Rock. First, use the newly collected Emerald Dragon Claw. Then, use the Ivory Dragon Claw you got from an earlier dungeon in that quest.

Comment: And for Reachwater Rock, you cannot drop the first claw as it is flagged as a Quest Item.