# Read XBOX 360 save files on my PC

Tags: xbox-360, dragon-age-origins

I have a memory stick that I have placed my DA:O saves files on, but I want to be able to read them on my PC (so I can use the toolset to extract the character settings/image).

Unfortunately the XBOX does not write simple files to the stick. Is there any way to get the individual save files onto the stick or extract them from out of the XBOX save format?

Comment: There was [a similar question for Skyrim](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/can-skyrims-console-savegames-be-migrated-to-pc) that said to use Modio: wonder if it'd work here.

Comment: I found [this thread](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/8/index/8630338/1#8686052) that supposedly describes a way to do this, but then later other people said it didn't work for them.  In general, the Xbox 360 saves are obfuscated (possibly encrypted), and accessing them on another device is not a supported use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is:

1. Get a USB key/drive that you don't care about and plug it into the front of your Xbox.
2. On the dashboard of the Xbox, go all the way right till you reach settings.
3. Select settings, go to Memory, and there should be the USB that you just plugged in.
4. Select the USB, then select Format. (Once this is done your USB is pretty much an Xbox harddrive that you can save profiles and game saves on.)
5. Once the USB is formatted, move whatever profiles and game saves to the newly formatted USB.
6. Now on either your laptop or desktop, go to www.gametuts.com and download the program MODIO.
7. Once that is done plug the USB into the laptop or desktop and open MODIO (you might have to download Winrar to extract it first).
8. Now that is done, the program will open and you can do many things from here, including:

   - modding different games
   - making personal backgrounds
   - even taking pictures off and putting them on your desktop as a jpg image.