# Fix for word of power quest bug at Arcwind Point

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

When I picked up the word of power at Arcwind Point, the quest didn't get removed from my quest log. If I select it, the arrow still points to the wall even though there is no word to collect anymore. The monks at High Hrothgar won't give me a new word power quest since they don't realize that I finished this one.

I can see in the Unofficial Elder Scrolls pages that this is a known issue.
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arcwind_Point

My question is now, is there anything I can do about it? I don't want to reload a previous save since I have done much since it happened. I didn't realize until hours afterwards what had happened.

Note: I am on Xbox 360 so the Unofficial Dawnguard Patch is not an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have XBox:
Look up Northwind point if your Arcwind wop quest won't complete, get the word there and the quest will finish.

Answer (score 10):

If you're playing on PC, you can use the console command `SetStage FreeFormHighHrothgarA 20` to complete the quest and allow you to take further quest, install the [Unofficial Skyrim Patch](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/19) to prevent such bugs in the future.

If you're not on PC, then you are out of luck, unless you [transfer your save to a PC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/can-skyrims-console-savegames-be-migrated-to-pc) and fix the bug there as described above.

Comment: Hi Kotekzot. As note in the question I am playing on the kexbox360.

Comment: And I don't have Skyrim on my PC so a transfer is not something I am desperate enough to try, not yet anyway.  :) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JonasSöderström http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/questions-where-op-has-mentioned-he-she-is-using-a-specific-platform-how-to-ans/5490#5490

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is, every time you get a word, you get that as fast as possible. If this is bugged, you reload the save game before you get Arcwind. If you are sent to Arcwind, just reload again.

https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Arngeir

In, my playthrough, Arcwind is the last word that Arngeir points to.

After I use console command to fix the issue, Arngeir says, "There is only silence right now. Perhaps later we will hear one of the lost Words"

That is even though I haven't found many words. For example, there is a word for slow time in labyryinthian. The fact that others ask how to find those words means they cannot get it easily from Arngeir

https://steamcommunity.com/app/489830/discussions/0/1729837292624291642/

Note: This is a bug in dawnguard.

The bug is related to 3 drain vitality shouts

https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/343786745998514805/

It seems that the "correct" way to solve the bug is to also read word wall in Northwind.

Fortunately, I choose to be a PC master race with the powah of console. So I just clear  using console command

> PC   360   PS3   NX   (Note: This bug does not occur if Dawnguard is
> not installed) If Arngeir gives Arcwind Point as the location of a
> Word of Power, finding the word wall and learning the word may not
> complete the "Find the Word of Power in Arcwind Point" miscellaneous
> quest objective. The quest marker will remain in front of the word
> wall. The word wall located at Northwind Summit completes this quest,
> but only if it has not been previously found.[1]
>
> PC   The console command `SetStage FreeFormHighHrothgarA 20` can be used to complete the quest, however Arngeir may give the quest again.
> Setting Arcwind Point as cleared via `SetLocationCleared fd685 1` will
> prevent getting sent there again.
>
> PC   360   PS3   Since finding the word wall at Northwind Summit is the only known way to resolve this bug, this can be avoided by
> discovering the Arcwind Point word wall before the Northwind Summit
> one. (in PC SSE 1.4.2.0.8 it greybeards might still give you this wall
> if you "fixed" this bug by getting Northwind Summit)

https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Arcwind_Point_(Skyrim)

Comment: I add something new. What is wrong anyway?