# Is there any way to replace a lost Dragon Priest mask?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find a lost item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item)

I found out about a spell I can get to summon a dragon priest and I need all 8 of the dragon priest masks. I know I have found them all but I think I may have dropped one by accident or put it in a chest somewhere not thinking I would need it. Mind you I probably did that close to the beginning of the game. Is there a way at all to find it again? Or am I surely out of luck. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

I am on Xbox 360, so console commands wont help.

Comment: For a more general solution check http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37365/23

Comment: You can [move the save-game to a PC][1] and fix it there.


  [1]: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/can-skyrims-console-savegames-be-migrated-to-pc

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get it back. Items in unsafe containers will usually disappear and randomly respawn in about 10 days in-game so anything you put inside it will gone forever.