# How do I get into Potema's Catecombs for the Dawnguard artifact?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm doing the Dawnguard radient quests that send you to three random locations for three random artifacts, and I've been sent to recover a hammer from Potema's catacombs. However, I've finished the Wolf Queen quest ages ago, so the entrance is once more behind an unpickable lock.

Since the dungeon is on the radient quest's location list, I assume there's supposed to be a way to get into it for the quest, but I can't figure out how. What am I supposed to do to get through this locked gate into the catacombs?

Comment: That's very unlucky of you. I bet it is a quest bug.

Comment: if it does, I'd suggest reloading immediately; it was the most boring question ever because the enemies only spawn the first time in response to the Potema events, so there's nothing to kill the second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on PC, you can use the console command `unlock` to unlock the door. If you're playing on console, you're likely out of luck - reload to an earlier save or live with the broken quest. Alternatively, you may be able to [move the save to a PC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/can-skyrims-console-savegames-be-migrated-to-pc) and fix it there with the console.

Comment: I ended up doing this, I did too much between getting the quest and actually going there. Definitely seems like a bad choice of quest location, since the enemies there don't respawn either.