# Serana disappeared

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I downloaded fifteen mods on my PS4 and was leaving the secret Thieves' Guild entrance when she disappeared. I already completed Dawnguard and also have Dragonborn and Hearthfire. I don't want to start over because some of the mods would be ineffective. Also, the other loads were auto-deleted. I also waited 24 hours and went to Fort Dawnguard and Volkihar Castle just in case, but she wasn't there. Do you have any suggestions/advice?

Comment: Not an answer, but having that many mods is likely to lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serana disappeared during dawnguard questline.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129631/serana-disappeared-during-dawnguard-questline) I know the situation in which you lost her is not identical, but based on my experience with the game the problem can seemingly randomly appear.

Comment: I fixed it by downloading a mod called ANA'S MODS it has a call serana spell but thanks anyway.