# What happened to the Daedric artifacts my follower was carrying?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I did the ritual to turn into a werewolf, my follower left me, but when I went back to Riften to get her back, she no longer has any of my deadric artifacts that she was holding for me. Is there somewhere she has put them or are they gone for good?

Answer (score 3):

NPCs in Skyrim don't actively store things in containers, so if your follower isn't carrying the items you've given them, then they are gone. If you play on PC, you can [give yourself the items back via console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item/37371#37371); if you're playing on a console you may try [moving the save over to PC](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40231/can-skyrims-console-savegames-be-migrated-to-pc), fixing it there and moving it back to console.

Comment: Are there any specific followers that lose items? For example, I dismiss Lidia several times, and yet every time I go back to her she is wearinhg the armour and has the weapons that I gave her.

Comment: @BlackHawk not that I know of.