# I lost a Daedric Ebony Blade, how can I find it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find a lost item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item)

I have been searching for every rare weapon in skyrim Xbox 360 elite. I had the ebony blade (daedric) and either dropped it in my home, put it in one of my chests or put it on a weapon rack and it has now disappeared. Please help and if you know a way to get two either would help. It looks like a katana.