# How can I find Morokei?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I found Morokei (Mask) and wasn't using it, so I gave it to my follower. I think she then died. I know where she died (if she did), but when I go there her body isn't there. And I'm on XBox 360 so your console cheats won't work here. I want it back because I got

> Got the Archmage Robes after Savos Aren died and I completed the College Quest

want to be a better mage. I also went back to where she was to see if she respawned for some reason (~10 hours have passed in real time). Any help?

Comment: You might want to clarify that you're talking about the mask, not the Priest.

Comment: @iLevin Yes that would help check edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find a lost item?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item)

Comment: xbox or not, there's no way you can find an item in skyrim unless you use the console, which you can't

Comment: So your saying ill never see morokei again?

Comment: not unless you get super lucky and either your companion shows up somewhere, or you run across her corpse before it despawns.

Comment: that would really suck since i cant get the 9th dragon priest mask ever then right?

Comment: @OutlawLemur "*im on xbox 360 so your console cheats wont work here*" - I'm so sorry. Without console commands AKA "cheats", there is only one Morokei's mask in the game, and it seems that you lost it. "*that would really suck since i cant get the 9th dragon priest mask ever then right?*" - Yes. =(

Comment: areana irileth i dont know how to spell her name but from azuras star

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i did some researching and decided to move my save game to a usb and use console commands on my friends pc version of skyrim using [this tutorial](http://www.justpressstart.net/?p=5650) to just add morokei back into my inventory

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't sure your follower died, make sure you check back where you originally picked them up in case they decided to go home,and make sure they aren't wandering around there.

Comment: i already checked there, but i will try waiting and see if that helps

Comment: also, if you aren't sure if your follower is alive, you can try hiring another follower.  if your follower is alive but lost, they will not join you.  if they join you, I'm afraid you are out of luck unless you can figure out where they died.

Comment: that item wasn't a quest item was it? would it return to the original place it was? stay on the ground where the dead body was? I'm trying to think in the terms of protected quest items. just a thought

Comment: @IrishJMA ok, i'll try that

Comment: @KiloJKilo no since it doesnt have to do with any quests, except for collecting all the dragon priest masks but that isn't a quest that you see on the quest page so it wouldnt be a quest item

Answer (score 0):

If you lost the mask by a glitch you can gain it back by going to the labyrinth, put on the wooden mask and activate the bust of the mask ur missing it will bring it back.