# Can i get back my lost items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find a lost item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item)

If I already lost some items in a chest that was not mine in skyrim, is it possible to got those things back? I don't care about normal items, I want back my Daedra artifacts.

I lost my things up on a ship named Dainty Sload, in a chest that its entering the ship
and it's near Solitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Items that disappeared due to cell resets are gone for good.

If you're playing on PC, you can add any items you need with the console.

Comment: No problems, if you consider the question answered you should click the grey checkmark next to the answer.