# Barrels in College of Winterhold were reset, I lost tons of items

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I safely store my stuff?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35314/where-can-i-safely-store-my-stuff)
>   [How can I find a lost item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item)

I thought that the College dorm room was a "safe stash" area. I put all of my spare potions and ingredients in the right most barrel in the cluster of three barrels in the back of the room. Not only that but the entire room was reset and everything I took was replaced. I've read that barrels and rooms may be reset if you don't return frequently, but that was not the case for me. I'd only been away from my dorm room for two (in game) days.Is there a way to get my stashed items back now? If not, how the HELL do I prevent this from happening again aside from entering my room once per day?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe the College dorm room is a 'safe' area for storage. The UESP Wiki lists [safe locations for storage in Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Category:Skyrim-Places-Safe), and the College dorm room area is not among them. Try one of the other locations there for storing your items, instead.

[The comments in an answer at this related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35998/4797) to yours also state that the College dorm room area is *not* safe for storage.