# Can you rebuy things from fences if they don't sell that item in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I sold something to Mallus Maccius and I actually need it now, it was a peice of armor and he does't carry that, is there anyway i can get it back?

Answer (score 2):

Unique items (e.g. Dragon Claws) remain in the inventory of the storekeepers indefinitely.  However items such as armour, whilst they will remain for a day or so, are liable to be lost permanently when the storekeeper's merchandise chest resets.  For more information on recovering lost items in Skyrim see [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item) (which again focusses mainly on unique items).

Comment: I reall y don't have any clue so could they be sold to someone else or something? It's the master robes of alteration and I can't get anotherone until I actually get my levels up some, so it would be really helpful!

Comment: @GTWBarrett Master robes of alteration are not a unique item, therefore that instance of them will have been lost forever when his chest restocked.  You can buy another set (with the correct level) at the College of Winterhold

Comment: "*Unique items (e.g. Dragon Claws) remain in the inventory of the storekeepers indefinitely.*" Have a source for that? By unique items, do you mean the items listed here: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unique_Items ?

Comment: @galacticninja It's mainly dragon claws and named weapons I have noticed this with, I'd do some experimenting but I don't have access to the game currently

Comment: @Rory If you've checked it out, please see this question of mine asking about that: [Are there items that when sold to merchants, will stay in their inventory forever (aside from Dragon Claws)?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/114689/4797)