# Are there items that when sold to merchants, will stay in their inventory forever (aside from Dragon Claws)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/114188/4797) in the question, "[Can you rebuy things from fences if they don't sell that item in skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/114185/4797)" states that:

> Unique items (e.g. Dragon Claws) remain in the inventory of the storekeepers indefinitely. However items such as armour, whilst they will remain for a day or so, are liable to be lost permanently when the storekeeper's merchandise chest resets.

**Aside from Dragon Claws, are there other "unique" items which will stay in a merchant's inventory forever? What determines if an item is considered "unique"?**

I would like to know as I regularly sell items I don't need to merchants, so they can be "deleted" in the game when the merchants have their inventory reset. I am not sure which items will indeed be removed with a merchant inventory reset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had several items stay far, far, longer than a day in a vendor's shop before. I am not sure if they stay indefinitely, though they seem to take a lot of time to go away.

The [UESP wiki lists two distinct types of permanent items](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Permanent_Items):

Type 1 - **Permanent (fully)**

- Keep their RefID number, when dropped into the world
- Do not lose any of their persistent traits when dropped into the world

Type 2 - **Permanent (until dropped)**

- May keep or lose their RefID number, when dropped into the world
- Lose any or all of their persistent traits when first dropped into the world.

---

[List of permanent items](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Permanent_Items#List_of_permanent_items)

The following items were found to be fully permanent:

1. Aetherial Crown [DG]
2. Ebony Blade
3. The Gauldur Amulet
4. Zephyr [DG]

The following items were found to be permanent until dropped (or placed on a weapon plaque):

1. Calcelmo's Ring
2. Declaration of War [DB]
3. Eduj
4. Emerald Dragon Claw
5. Halldir's Staff - the one you get from Halldir's ash pile, not the one which drops near it
6. Ironhand Gauntlets - looted from Hajvarr Iron-Hand
7. Iron Dragon Claw
8. Journals of Ralys Sedaris [DB] - all volumes
9. Klimmek's Supplies
10. Letter from a Friend - all instances
11. Okin
12. Ruby Dragon Claw
13. Saerek's Skull Key - only if you do not use it to awaken Otar the Mad (awaken him with shout or rune spell instead)
14. Staff of Hag's Wrath
15. The Aetherium Wars [DG] - only the first copy, obtained before or during associated quest
16. Torsten's Skull Key - only if you do not use it to awaken Otar the Mad (awaken him with shout or rune spell instead)
17. Whiterun guard's armor, shield, helmet, gloves and boots - looted from Mirmulnir

Note: Permanent weapons may fail to prevent corpses from disappearing, although they will remain in respawning containers.

Comment: Which items are those?

Comment: Well the weird thing for me was that it seemed to be mostly regular armor that took a while to fade. I know it was mine because I always tempered it and enchanted it before I sold it. I did however find a list of items that should work anyway, see answer.