# Command to find unique object in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm missing page 10 of Jiub Opus quest. Adding the item with `additem` will not complete the quest, so I need the reference to the existing object.

What can I do? The item is not where its supposed to be (on the barrel).

Since the object is unique, a command like 'find all references' would be nice. So I could use `moveto player`, that would work right?

Comment: did you try the additem command, then drop it out of inventwory and pick it up again?

Comment: You could complete the quest using setStage

Comment: There is no way to do this other than by using the refid provided and adding it that way via `player.additem`. Sorry mate. You'd have to write your own mod to do it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answers to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item), there is no way to search for the actual in-game items.

My suggestion is to leave the cell and wait for 10 days to make it respawn, and then see if the page is where it's supposed to be.