# What happened to my follower's inventory?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had a partner in Skyrim on PS3, she was part of the Dark Brotherhood after they moved to Dawnstar and she had a lot on her like all the Labrynthian Masks.

So I got the Skyrim legendary edition and I spent most of my time on my home (in the Hearthfire DLC) and the game was lagging really bad. I dismissed my parter to get rid of the lag (which worked), but when I went to get my partner back I realised that her inventory was wiped. The only thing she had was a sword?

I'm trying to figure out where all my stuff I gave is does anyone know what happened to my stuff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find a lost item?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/how-can-i-find-a-lost-item)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate because of the specific issue of a Dark Brotherhood Initiate acting different than a regular companion, which is addressed in the answer below.

Answer (score 7):

If your companion was a Dark Brotherhood Initiate, I'm afraid you're out of luck. According to the [Dark Brotherhood Initiate discussion page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Dark_Brotherhood_Initiate#Serious_Bug) on the UESP Wiki, along with some [other forum threads](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/65727763), the Dark Brotherhood Initiates will often reset when dismissed, which resets the contents of their inventory. If you were on PC, you could get your items back by adding them with console commands, but since you're playing on a console, there isn't anything you can do other than revert to a save when the initiate was still your companion, and remove the items from their inventory before dismissing them.